# No audit results

Tags: oracle, audit-trail

I have been testing audit area in Oracle 11g. Unfortunately, after I go through below-described steps, I get no results in audit tables. I am connected to the database as store. Why is that?

```
GRANT AUDIT SYSTEM TO store; 
GRANT AUDIT ANY TO store;

AUDIT CREATE ANY TABLE BY store;

CREATE TABLE test_mj_aud(
   id  INTEGER);

INSERT INTO test_mj_aud
VALUES (1);
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test_mj_aud;

SELECT * FROM user_audit_trail; --no results
SELECT * FROM db_audit_trail; --no results
```

Comment: Is auditing enabled? Is it set to [DB or operating system](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50514)?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right Thanks.